# Syntax error in gridview delete option

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

I added delete to my gridview and I get syntax error I don't understand 
here is my code:

```
DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Games] 
                 WHERE [Team1] = @Team1, [Team2] = @Team2"

InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [Games] ([Team1], [Team2], [GameType], [Time]) VALUES (@Team1, @Team2, @GameType, @Time)"

UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [Games] SET [Team1] = @Team1, [Team2] = @Team2, [GameType] = @GameType, [Time] = @Time WHERE [Team1] = @Team1">

<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Team1" Type="string" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Team2" Type="string" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="GameType" Type="string" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM [Games] WHERE [Team1] = @Team1,[Team2]=@Team2
```

Should be

```
DELETE FROM [Games] WHERE [Team1] = @Team1 AND [Team2]=@Team2
```

Notice the "And" between the conditions.

FYI - Posting the error message in future will stop you getting down votes but anyway..